# what is the default method when using urllib2.urlopen() to open an URL 'get' or 'post'

Tags: http, python-2.7

```
import urllib2,urllib
params = {}
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://somewhere/',urllib.urlencode(params))
```

In urlopen() method, there isn't argv for the method 'get' or 'post'.
Can this method figure out 'get' or 'post' by the url required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It figures out `GET` or `POST` based on the params given. In your case it would be `POST` since a dictionary of params is provided.

to use `POST` you can do it like this (from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html))

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query", params)
print f.read()
```

Notice we pass a dictionary here to the function.

To use `GET` we simply pass the URL alone (here we use string interpolation to add the params to the URL instead of passing it to URL lib)

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query?%s" % params)
print f.read()
```

Comment: I was about to post the exactly same answer. Oh. Too late. :(

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> `urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])`
>
> `data` may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server,
>   or `None` if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the
>   only ones that use `data`; the HTTP request will be a `POST` instead of a
>   `GET` when the `data` parameter is provided. `data` should be a buffer in
>   the standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. The
>   `urllib.urlencode()` function takes a mapping or sequence of 2-tuples
>   and returns a string in this format. urllib2 module sends `HTTP/1.1`
>   requests with Connection:close header included.